# Signaling Cell Changes across multiple QSqlDatabase to the same SQliteFile

Tags: python, sql, qt, sqlite

I have PyQt application which uses SQLite files to store data and would like to allows multiple users to read and write to the same database.  It uses QSqlDatabase and QSqlTableModels with item views for reading and editing.

As is multiple users can launch the application and read/write to different tables.  The issue is this:
Say user1's application reads table A then user2 writes to index 0,0 on table A.  Since user1 application has already read and cached that cell and doesn't see user2's change right away.  The Qt item view's will update when the dataChanged signal emits but in this case the data is being changed by another application instance.  Is there some way to trigger file changes by another application instance.  What's the best way to handle this.

I'm assuming this is really best solved by using an SQL server host connection rather than SQLite for the database, but in the realm of SQLite what would be my closest workaround option?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has no mechanism by which another user can be notified.

You have to implement some communication mechanism outside of SQLite.